# Étymologie de « rez-de-chaussée » ?

Tags: étymologie

Je me pose une question  : d'où peut bien venir le mot « rez-de-chaussée » ?

Comment: As-tu fais des recherches ? Qu'as-tu trouvé ?

Comment: Que l'origine est vraiment incertaine, les sources sont plus ou moins contradictoires.

Comment: Peux-tu ajouter les étymologies que tu as trouvé à ta question (comme [celle-ci](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/rez-de-chauss%C3%A9e)) ? Avoir tous les éléments aidera à répondre avec précision.

Comment: @ThomasFrancois Justement ton lien au CNRTL ne donne pas l'étymologie. Il ne donne même pas la formation du mot, ce qui est nécessaire pour remonter la chaîne, facile quand on le sait déjà ou pour un francophone, mais pas évident pour tout le monde.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En complément à ce qu'on a déjà dit [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/20009/3177). Un adjectif comme [*ras(e)*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ras/2) (*rasus*, p.p. de *radere*), pour *jusqu'au bord*, est une ancienne réfection basée sur res, reiz ; [rez](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rez) est un doublet, qu'on avait en préposition (*rez terre*), avec l'idée de *raser, à ras le*  etc. Le *rez de chauciee* c'est d'abord toute la *surface du terrain au niveau de la chaussée* ou de la rue ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/rez-de-chauss%C3%A9e)), puis par métonymie la partie d'un immeuble qui y est située (1548) ; *rez-de-chaussée* est attesté en 1450 (DHLF/2012). Chaussée fut d'abord [*chauciee*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/chauss%C3%A9e), peut-être par référence à la chaux chez les Romains. Le TLFi donne comme premier emploi attesté un bail de 1365 dans son sens original :

> [...] une maison toute et la court d'icelle, sicomme tout se comporte
>   et estent, haut, bas, devant, derreres et en parfont, avecques une
>   estable estant et seant derreres ladicte court ; enclavee en la maison
>   de Jehan Françoys, taillieur de robes et sergent a verge du roy nostre
>   sire ou Chastellet de Paris, sicomme icelle estable se comporte et
>   estent depuis **rez de chauciee** et pavement de ladicte court jusques au
>   premier planchier estant sur ycelle estable, les quelles meson, court
>   et estables les diz baillieurs se disoient avoir de leur conquest,
>   assises a Paris, en la rue aus Oues [...]
>
> [ Extrait du bail Phelippe Giffart ds. [*Chartes et documents
>   de l'Abbaye de Saint-Magloire*](https://books.google.com/books?id=lUPkAAAAMAAJ&dq=Chartes%20et%20doc.%20de%20l%27abbaye%20de%20St-Magloire&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=chauciee), Yvette de Montenon (1976) ]

Ça vient d'à ras le sol...

Comment: ***Chauciee*** : bonne pioche historique :) -- Est-ce que le manque d'accents sur le texte en référence est dû à l'imprimeur ou à mon ignorance des typographies anciennes ?

Comment: @cl-r Ouais, vous devez regarder 1976, mais le bail est écrit au 14e alors que l'accent aigu est du 16e...

Comment: Me voilà moins ignorant... merci de m'avoir fait rencontrer leur géniteur, Geoffroy Tory.

Answer (score 8):

**Rez-de-chaussée** est formé avec *rez*, *de* et *chaussée*.

Sur *rez-de-chaussée* on a formé  *rez-de-jardin*, *rez-de-métro*, *rez-de-terrasse*, mais c'est la seule survivance du mot *rez* en français contemporain et le mot n'est plus employé tout seul.

*Rez* est un ancien doublet de *ras*, issu du latin *rasus* participe passé de *radere* qui veut dire « raser effleurer ». On trouve en ancien français (XII<sup>e</sup> siècle) *a res de*. Au XV<sup>e</sup> siècle sont apparus *rez pied* et *rez terre* qui sont restés employés jusqu'au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle dans un usage archaïque (précise le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française*). Le [CNRTL atteste](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rez) un emploi de *rez-terre* en 1963.

> Le mot *rez-de-chaussée* a d'abord désigné la surface d'un terrain situé de niveau avec une chaussée, une rue, avant de prendre, par métonymie, la valeur moderne de « partie d'une maison au ras du sol » (1548), servant à désigner un appartement, un logement ainsi situé (1835). (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*).